# How do i convert this into a simple key value pair?

Tags: php, select, sqlite

I've been breaking my head to figure out how to get this done.

Ok, so i'm creating an SQLite3 database (which has only username and password) for a login system for my web app. I created the table, inserted values and all that. Everything works perfectly.

How do i write code in such a way that the queried array is in a simple key-value pair of username=>password?

Here is the code:

```
function db_select($username, $password) {

$db = db_connect();

$result = $db->query("SELECT '$username','$password; FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'") or die('Query failed');

if($result) {
    $row = $result->fetchArray();
    print_r($row);
}
}
```

This is the output:

```
Array ( [0] => User ['User'] => User [1] => Pass ['Pass'] => Pass )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite like..

```
$usrarr = array();
if($result) {
    $row = $result->fetchArray();
    $usrarr[$row['User']]=$row['Pass'];
}
print_r($usrarr);
```

Comment: Thank you! Modified it a bit and it worked like a charm.